# How can I create a multiple wildcards with the single domain name?

Tags: dns

Is that possible to create wildcard records like ***-demo.example.com, 
    *-abc.example.com and *-xyz.example.com?** all are pointing to different IP to CNAME.

Actually, I'm developing an application  and that is required to have the multiple wildcards with the single domain name.

```
*-demo.example.com
*-abc.example.com
*-xyz.example.com
```

And all records are pointing to different IP or CNAME.

Comment: Did you try creating them?

Comment: Yes, I have tried but technically this is not possible. I'm managing doing manual DNS entry.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not. Wildcards are by definition whole labels with the content "*", and they must be the leftmost label. See [RFC 1034](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1034.txt) section 4.3.3.